# Different interaction p-values in R versus SPSS

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, spss

I originally ran my data in SPSS because figuring out the lmer package took some time for me to learn. I spent a few weeks writing up a script in R, but my output in R is different than what I'm getting using SPSS.

I have 3 Fixed Effects: Group, Session, and TrialType.

When I ran a mixed model in SPSS, I got the interaction Group*Session p=.08 OR p=.02, depending on which covariance structure I used. This is partly the reason I wanted to use R, because I didn't have enough information to help me decide which structure to use.

Here are my models in R. I'm using Log Likelihood Test to get a p-value for this Group*Session interaction.

```
 Mod2 = lmer(accuracy ~ group*session*trialtype + (trialtype|subject), REML=F, data=data, 
        control = lmerControl(optimizer = "optimx", optCtrl=list(method='L-BFGS-B'))))
 Mod5 = lmer(accuracy ~ session + trialtype + group + session*trialtype + trialtype*group + (trialtype|subject), 
        data=data, REML=FALSE,
        control = lmerControl(optimizer = "optimx", optCtrl=list(method='L-BFGS-B')))

 anova(Mod2, Mod5)

 Data: data
 Models:
 Mod5: accuracy ~ session + trialtype + group + session * trialtype + 
 Mod5:     trialtype * group + (trialtype | subject)
 Mod2: accuracy ~ group * session * trialtype + (trialtype | subject)
 Df     AIC     BIC logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
 Mod5 23 -961.32 -855.74 503.66  -1007.3                         
 Mod2 27 -956.32 -832.38 505.16  -1010.3 2.9989      4      0.558
```

I'll also note that I added the lmerControl based on the 2 warning/error messages I was getting. When I added, this, I got the singular boundary warning message.

Please comment if I need to specify additional information. Thank you!

Here is my syntax from SPSS:

```
 MIXED Acc BY Test TrialType Group
   /CRITERIA=CIN(95) MXITER(100) MXSTEP(10) SCORING(1) SINGULAR(0.000000000001) HCONVERGE(0,
ABSOLUTE) LCONVERGE(0, ABSOLUTE) PCONVERGE(0.000001, ABSOLUTE)
   /FIXED=Test TrialType Group Test*TrialType Test*Group TrialType*Group Test*TrialType*Group |
SSTYPE(3)
   /METHOD=ML
   /PRINT=COVB DESCRIPTIVES G  SOLUTION
   /RANDOM=INTERCEPT TrialType | SUBJECT(Subject) COVTYPE(CS)
   /REPEATED=Test | SUBJECT(Subject) COVTYPE(ID).
```

Comment: Is it possible that R is not recognizing a grouping variable in my data? I'm not sure how to identify this or correct it

Comment: Are all grouping variables declared somewhere `as.factor`?

Comment: Your question title suggests you are interested in the $p$-value of the interaction effect, but `anova(Mod2, Mod5)` compares the fit of the model with and without. A $p$-value for the interaction could be obtained by running a summary, although you'd have to use the package `lmerTest`, as `lme4` does not (for good reason) include $p$-values in the summary by default.

Comment: I don't think the models are equivalent: In SPSS, you include the `\REPEATED` statement whose analogue is not included in R. I think you'd need the `nlme` package for that anyway.

Comment: @FransRodenburg well I thought I was comparing my full model against a model without the interaction I'm interested in. Is this not the way to see if an interaction is significant?

Comment: @BruceET Yes. I made sure to make them into factors, which was why I had to add the additional control=lmerControl to the script, otherwise I received warning messages

Comment: @COOLSerdash You're right, I completely overlooked that. Thank you! I will try nlme

Comment: The significance of an interaction term is whether or not its coefficient differs significantly from zero.